# (py)Spark getItem() in SQL syntax

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The n-th item of an Array typed column can be retrieved using `getitem(n)`. Map typed columns can be taken apart using either `getItem(key)` or `'column.key'`. Is there a similar syntax for Arrays?

Context: goal is to take specific fields from a massively nested json in a readable fashion.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)

sample = spark.createDataFrame([[[1,2,3]]], ['a'])

sample.show
```

---

```
+---------+
|        a|
+---------+
|[1, 2, 3]|
+---------+
```

**works**

```
sample.select(f.col('a').getItem(0))
sample.select('a')
```

**does not work**

```
sample.select('a.0')
sample.select('a[0]')
# etc
```

Comment: if you register the sample as temporate table, then spark.sql(select a[0] from T) should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're forgetting `expr` function when using sql.

```
sample = spark.createDataFrame([[[1,2,3]]], ['a'])

sample.show()    

#+---------+
#|        a|
#+---------+
#|[1, 2, 3]|
#+---------+

sample.select(expr("a[0]")).show()

#+----+
#|a[0]|
#+----+
#|   1|
#+----+
```

Comment: yes! makes my supernested query a lot easier on the eyes!